# application size doubles on repair

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am working on an application which is having an option for repair. I have scheduled one of my cleanup custom action for temp files after InstallFinalize. Now when I am doing repair of the application from the control panel, after completion of the repair the application size in the control panel is getting double.

If I run this custom action before InstallFinalize, then size in the control panel is proper but the temps files are not getting deleted.

please, suggest me the right sequence for scheduling the cleanup custom action. so that it will work fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The size displayed by Windows Installer in Control Panel is calculated automatically based on multiple criteria. Most of them cannot be controlled.

Also, on some machines Windows Installer can also decide to use an incorrect size even if you schedule your action before InstallFinalize.

So you should make sure that your installer works as expected and ignore the Control Panel size. If this really bugs you, you can try setting [ARPSIZE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367748%28VS.85%29.aspx) installer property to the size you want.