# application size doubles on repair in control panel

Tags: wix, arp

I have an installer which is having repair option. While installation I am copying some 50MB of temp files in the temp folder, which I want to delete at the end after installation.I am doing so by a custom action which deletes the temp folder created by me.

Now the problem is when I am doing the repair, size in the control panel is getting double each time. If I do not delete those 50MB of temp files, on repair size remains the same.

Is that I am missing on the right sequence here or on something else?
please guid me

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: possible duplicate of [application size doubles on repair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156487/application-size-doubles-on-repair)

Answer (score 1):

Usually Windows Installer determines required sizes during [CostInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368050%28VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) and [CostFinalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368048%28VS.85%29.aspx) actions. So you can try moving your temporary files custom actions before, between or after these actions to see if it solves anything.

If it doesn't and ARPSIZE doesn't work for you, there's not much you can do.